# How to include the value of a parameter into a string in a makefile

Tags: c, makefile, optional-parameters

I have a makefile and I pass a parameter to it through command line. Say I pass parameter for clock frequency such as this.

```
make run FREQ=500
```

In my makefile, I want to include the value of FREQ inside a string, for example, I want to expand it like this.

```
RUN_FLG = "--frequency = 500"
```

I know you can use $(FREQ) if you are using that parameter normally (not inside strings), but how do you expand it inside a string?

Comment: Have you tried it using the same syntax? I don't think make is aware of quote-enclosed strings as everything is seen as a string.

Comment: Pubby - Haven't tried it yet, but I'll try so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` doesn't know what a string is; you embed the macro reference into the string the same as outside a string:

```
DEFAULT_FREQ = 60
FREQ         = $(DEFAULT_FREQ)

RUN_FLG = "--frequency=$(FREQ)"
```

I've 'corrected' the spacing in the `--frequency`; you would not normally have the `=` separate from the option text, and the value would also follow without spaces.

I've provided a default value for FREQ inside the `makefile` so that if it is invoked without any `FREQ=500` override, you still have the default value as part of `$(RUN_FLG)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$(value)`

Example:

```
freq = 500
x = "--frequency = $(freq)"

run:
    @$(/bin/echo -e) $(x)
```

Output of `make -n`:

```
"--frequency = 500"
```